# how to compress all folders in a directory

Tags: bash, compression

I have a directory full of folders and I was wondering 
if there is any command to compress all the folders in a directory **X** with date in the name of the file **and not** *update* old ones in case they existed?

Thanks!

Comment: You have a directory full of folders? Is a folder something different from a directory on your system? I always thought folders were MickeySoft's newspeak for directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here a shorty with strong xz compression

```
cd /ur/directory/where/the/content/is
backupfile="`date +"%y-%m-%d`";
targetdir="/where/u/want"
[ ! -f "$targetdir/$backupfile".tar.xz ] && tar -xJvf "$targetdir/$backupfile".tar.xz *
```